# Why dont my Divs span 100% of the width?

Tags: css, html, width

I have a really dumb question to ask.

I am trying to make a div span 100% of the width of a webpage, but it doesn't reach. I want it to be dynamic (not specify the width in px) and I definitely don't want it to make a horizontal scroll bar appear.

I'm trying to make something similar to Stack Overflow's 100% page width 'alerts' which tell you when you've earned a new badge.

Screenshot of my site:
[image: Screenshot of my site. Note how the pink banner and green banner leave gaps where the sky blue background is shown.]

Code for the pink banner div

```
<div width='100%' style="padding:0px; background-color:FF0099; background-image:url('pics/pink_bg.png'); ">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Right click and use "Inspect element".  Use that to see what it's embedded in, as well as any default margins or insets that you don't know about.  You might be surprised.

Comment: Fixed it. Margin in the body was automatically set to 8px. If you repost this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: go ahead and accept one of the answers that's saying the same thing.  I don't care about reputation points any more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your **html body** tag might have *padding or margin* css. you should set those to **zero**(0). I hope it will help.

Comment: First answer to mention margin, not just padding was accepted. Thank you all for your help. Right click using Chrome to "Inspect Element" was how I figured out the error of my ways.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have padding on your body, which is preventing the div from expanding all the way.

Comment: Code for Body: `<body bgcolor="skyblue">`

Comment: Style for Body: `body {}` ... when I change the style for Body to: `body { padding:0px; }` nothing changes

Comment: inspect the body to see what styling it is getting first

Answer (score 2):

In your css file, ensure that you don't have any padding on the body. If you don't have anything you can try adding this:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: also make sure that your body margin is set to zero!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a css for the body to remove the padding and margin:

```
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Also you can apply just to left, right top and bottom margins:

```
body {
padding-top:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite easy. Make sure the parent container for pink banner div has 0 padding and 0 margin. In this case I'm assuming the container for your pink banner is just the body tag. Now copy the following snippet inside your head section of the page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }
</style>
```

The html for your pink banner is also not correct. Replace

```
<div width='100%' style="padding:0px; background-color:FF0099; background-image:url('pics/pink_bg.png'); ">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

with

```
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width=100%; height:25px; background-color:#FF0099; background-image:url('pics/pink_bg.png');" >
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

at the beginning of your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I had a great big white line on the right hand side of my page. I found the following which was a life saver:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A the beginning of each CSS document I always type:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I never have any problems with unwanted outer margins or padding with that code.